# Calculating shortest route in Geopackage/SQLite

Tags: spatialite, routing, sqlite, geopackage

Are there any graph analysis tools written for a SQLite database? What I'm looking for is something akin to pgRouting but for SQLite. I can't find anything with a significant user base, which is surprising to me.

Comment: But you found things with an *insignficant* user base? What things are they? Why is user-base size important to you?

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/jorgeliecer/NiuRouting
It may work for my needs, but with a small project like this there's very little certainty about future support and updates.

Comment: I suspect the lack of a "pgrouting" for GPKG is that since the DB doesn't run on a server most people will use a client to the DB and read the spatial data and run routing on that - using something in Python or C - that can read any OGR spatial data source...